# Doxygen output for C

Tags: c, doxygen

I have used Doxygen for years with C++ code. I'd like to use it with some C code that I'm working on, but the output is less than optimal. The "Classes" tab in the top bar shows only the `struct` definitions, not the functions in the file. I have to click on the "Files" tab and then the name of the header file to view the functions it contains.

Is there any way to modify the output of Doxygen so that it is more suitable to code written in C? Or at the very least, remove the "Classes" tab and provide only the "Files" view?

Comment: i/**
 * @defgroup MY_C_CLASS
 * @{
 */

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a layout file in addition to the normal config file:

```
doxygen -l layout.xml
```

You can edit that; this controls the basic format of the interface.  If you want to remove the "Classes" tab, locate:

```
<tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="Types">
    [...]
</tab>
```

And remove it or change `visible` to "no".

C functions and datatypes are usually grouped together in files in a non-random way, so the "Files" tab alone may be sufficient for you.  If not, use groups:

```
\ingroup foobar
```

Can be added to struct and function definitions, etc.  You then need a

```
\defgroup foobar Description of foobar.
```

somewhere.  This will then be used by

```
<tab type="modules" visible="yes" title="Modules" intro=""/>
```

From `layout.xml`, producing a possibly more intuitive interface than "Files" (e.g., struct documentation from a `.h` and function documentation from a `.c` are organized together if they are in the same group), akin to how "Classes" works with C++.

There's more about this stuff in [the doxygen site](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can set

```
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES
```

in the config file, to get output that is more C oriented.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the structure and function declarations of you C class  MY_C_CLASS in the following construct

i always put the doxygen help for the function in the help file, so that it is grouped with the class group.

```
/**
 * @defgroup MY_C_CLASS
 * @brief MY_C_CLASS class
 * describe here what it is all about.
 * @{
 */

 typedef struct tagMY_C_CLASS {

 } MY_C_CLASS;

 /**
  * @brief constructor
  * @return status; -1 on failure.
  */
 int MY_C_CLASS_init(MY_C_CLASS *void);

/**
 * @}
 */
```